# Py error could not broadcast input array from shape (244,244,3) into shape (224,224,3) arrays have the same shape (224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, numpy

this similar to other questions where there is an error related to "broadcasting" a np array with a shape of (244, 244, 3) and a np array with a shape of (244, 244, 4) but in this case both arrays have the same shape (244, 244, 3) i am new if have done this incorrectly let me now thanks code is hear

```
import tensorflow.keras
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np


SuccsesCriteria = 0.5999999
global data
global model


def start():
    global data
    global model
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('Asstets/keras_model.h5')
    data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)


def imageToArray(image):
    #size = (224, 224)
    #image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # turn the image into a numpy array
    image_array = np.asarray(image)
    normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1
    return normalized_image_array


def predictionToBool(_prediction):
    for _p in _prediction:
        if _p[0] >= SuccsesCriteria:
            print('Cat')
            return True
        elif _p[2] >= SuccsesCriteria:
            print('No Cat')
            return True
        elif _p[1] >= SuccsesCriteria:
            print('???')
            return False


def predictFromImage(image):
    global data
    global model
    data[0] = imageToArray(image)
    # run the inference
    return model.predict(data)
```

full error

```
2021-05-12 09:11:49.477186: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in the save file, so the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/***************/Keras/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(AI.predictFromImage(Cam.getCamImage()))
  File "/Users/***************/Keras/AI.py", line 44, in predictFromImage
    data[0] = imageToArray(image)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (244,244,3) into shape (224,224,3)
```